AC power failure alarm light
I wanted to make a simple circuit that shows an indicator light to glow when a load is switched OFF. When I turn OFF both the switches for the load then the indicator light should turn ON glowing that there is a power failure/no power and when I switch them ON then the indicator light should stop glowing.
I can do this for small DC circuit with the help of an NPN and a couple of resistors (logic inverter). For AC circuit I can still manage with this Normally Closed relay circuit (like shown diagram).
I was hoping that can we do it without the use of a relay and utilize Triacs or SCR instead?


how about solid state relays?

Solid state relays requires dc electronics components to make it works. So they require to have it like a module which triggers a logic voltage usually 5v or 3.3v. I will have to make additional PSU to run that solid relay.

Yes, you would. Like you need the wheels to make a car.

You can buy Solid-State Relays with 120/240 VAC input. Search for "solid state relay 240v ac input". Here is one: https://www.amazon.com/Solid-State-Relay-Module-Output/dp/B0CBNQ52C8

@Mattman944 It should work but isn't a overkill?

for just on/off detection? easy: simply send the AC though a bridge rectifier and smooth it into DC. then it's easy to detect the DC. KISS.

"power failure" and "no power" are concepts with a HUGE difference. NEVER must be mixed into the same indicator.

@dandavis can you show me with a crude diagram or a circuit.

Are they separate switches for the L and the N or a 2-pole switch? Why are you switching N?

@Transistor It is a double pole switch.

Something like this should work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Suppose that both switches are closed. Neither Q1 nor Q2 conducts, since there is 0V from base to emitter on both. No gate current flows. TRI1 does not conduct. The light is off.

simulate this circuit
Now suppose that both switches are open.

If load has low impedance, R3 and R4 set a potential at half-supply, that the bases are then connected to via base resistor. Q1 and Q2 will be ON in their respective half-cycles.

The higher the load impedance, the more base current will flow through R3 and R4, and less through the load. Q1 and Q2 will still be ON in their respective half-cycles.



simulate this circuit
Now suppose that only SW1 is open. Q1 does not conduct. But Q2 conducts in its half cycle. The NO POWER light is at half-brightness.

simulate this circuit
And finally, suppose that SW2 is open. Q2 does not conduct. But Q1 does conduct during its half-cycle.

simulate this circuit
If we'd like the NO POWER light to be ON in both half-cycles when only one of the switches is open, we can add some more transistors and another triac to do that.

simulate this circuit
The transistors need to be able to withstand 450V C-E at least, since they are exposed to full mains voltage, with transients.

I tried your first circuit with simulator and this the result.  Falstad Simulator

@Kokachi I have no idea how well Falstad can simulate this. I also didn’t check if the resistor values you chose are OK.

I recommend buying an off-the-shelf module (see my comment). But if you want to build it yourself, the Solid-State Relays with AC inputs have something like this inside.

Left: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply
Right: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/moc3023m-d.pdf
If your indicator is very low power, you may be able to omit the power triac and drive the indicator directly from the MOC3022.
The values shown are probably not ideal for your application, you have some design to perform.
C1 must be an X-rated cap, suitable for AC line use.
C2 can probably be considerably smaller, you don't need smooth DC here.
If you are in an electrically noisy environment, you may need a snubber and transient suppressor, see figure 8 in the MOC3022 datasheet.

I looked at the circuit and from my understanding I think the capacitive power supply is for powering the IR led inside the optocoupler to trigger the Diac. But the Triac will close the circuit only if the gate is energized. What I want is to close the circuit only if the gate is not energized.

You are correct, I have the polarity backwards, the circuit needs an inversion somewhere, probably the right side. What is the current draw of the indicator? Can it be an LED integrated into the design?

The LED indicator will be about 50mA. The indicator system should be integrated with a resistor and a diode for current limiting and compatible for AC line.

Your requirements are a little underdefined. You haven't specified what should happen if the load fails (bulb blows, etc.). However, ...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. A simple neon circuit.
This circuit uses two neon lamps (with built-in series resistors), one across each contact of the switch.

When the switches are closed each indicator is shorted out and will not light.
When the switches are open the neons are in series with the lamp (which has much lower relative resistance). Both will glow. You might find that 230 V neons are too dim in series but 120 V neons should work fine.

If you only want one indicator then hide the other!

On any other day I would say you're idea will work but the tiny neon bulbs are just not bright enough for my project requirement.
